# Add attribute of href inside li with a particular data-id in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to add `target="blank"` to the a tag with `li data-id="232"`

```
<li class="" data-id="232">
    <a href="new.html">
    New Page    
  </a>
</li>
```

using jQuery.

Comment: It should be `jQuery('li[data-id="232"] a').prop('target', '_blank')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.attr` with the following jQuery selector:

```
$('li[data-id="232"] a').attr('target', '_blank')
```

Comment: [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target) is a property of `Anchor` not `li` element